# In-array comparison in F#

Tags: arrays, f#, comparison

Let's say that I want to do some in-array comparison in F#, e.g. determine whether a given integer array `arr` contains integers in strictly increasing order. I would do it like this:

```
let arri = 
    arr
    |> Array.mapi (fun i e -> i, e)

let isArrStrictlyIncreasing =
    arri
    |> Array.tryFind (fun e -> 
        if fst e = arri.Length - 1 then 
            false 
        else 
            snd e >= snd arri.[1 + fst e])
    |> Option.isNone
```

However, I am wondering if there is a more concise, "functional" way of making such in-array comparisons without the use of `Array.mapi` and `if-else`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way:

```
let isincr arr = 
   arr 
   |> Array.fold (fun (a,b) (c) -> ((b<c && a)),c) (true,System.Int32.MinValue) 
   |> fst
```

Comment: My FSI throws an "This expression was expected to have type bool but here has type int" for `System.Int32.MinValue`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to keep the accumulator - fixed

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do the following?

```
let expected = [| candidate.[0] .. candidate.[0] + candidate.Length - 1 |]
candidate = expected
```

This simply builds the array you'd expect, and uses F#'s **Structural Equality** to compare the two arrays.

---

A more general alternative might be this:

```
let isOrdered arr = arr |> Array.sort = arr

let hasDistinctMembers (arr : 'a array) = 
    let distinct = arr |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.toArray
    distinct.Length = arr.Length

let isStrictlyIncreasing arr = arr |> isOrdered && arr |> hasDistinctMembers
```

Usage:

```
> isStrictlyIncreasing [| 7; 11; 8 |];;
val it : bool = false
> isStrictlyIncreasing [| 7..33 |];;
val it : bool = true
> isStrictlyIncreasing [| 7; 8; 11 |];;
val it : bool = true
> isStrictlyIncreasing [| 7; 7; 8; 11 |];;
val it : bool = false
```

Comment: I think this might fail if there were gaps in the input (i.e `[|1;4|]`)

Comment: Ah, you didn't want a strictly *monotonically* increasing sequence :)